# jquery mobile popstate events X steps back

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I'm working on jquery mobile and I'm trying to intercept history changes events. After inspecting jqm sources I have managed to have back and forward events and $.mobile.changePage events successfully intercepted. 
Now if I have history.go(-3) the popstate event is fired but I have no idea how many steps the browser has gone back.

Below is how I'm intercepting the events. This works perfectly on all mobile browsers.

```
$.mobile.window.bind({
    "popstate.history": function(event){
        //Triggered for forward and change page events
    },
    "hashchange.history":  function(event){
        //Triggered for back events
    }
});
```

**NOTE** : It should be compatible with all recent native mobile browsers : android 2.1 + , BB10 , Windows phone 8 and ios 5+